# C: Reading SUB char from file

Tags: c, file, stream

I am writing a series of char on a file, generated by random int.
Sometimes the file presents the SUB char, which should be a char used  in the place of a character that is recognized to be invalid or erroneous.
When I have to read this file, I use the function fcsanf(), but the reading ends when fcanf() reads the SUB char.

This is the cycle I am using:

```
while(fscanf(f, "%c", &buffer) != EOF){
  ...
}
```

I just need to keep reading after I find the SUB char, and considering the SUB char as the bit sequence it represents.

edit: i'm adding an image of my code because it seems having formatting problems..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAtxg.png)

Comment: What is posted is not enough to replicate the issue.  Add more detail like how is "reading ends when fcanf() reads the SUB char." demonstrated.

Comment: What is a SUB char?

Comment: @WeatherVane Perhaps ASCII 26 `SUB`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character this is the SUB char.

Comment: @chux with the reading ends i mean it goed off the cycle, it's like it is reading EOF wich is the exit condition of my while..

Comment: In olden days, character 26 (ctrl-Z) was used as an end-of-textfile marker, as part of the file. So that may be why the reading ends.

Comment: @Flavio Post code that shows "with the reading ends i mean it goed off the cycle" as that is more illustrative than describing this code.  By providng code that in itself demonstrates the problems, we all benefit in a more rapid complete solution.

Comment: @WeatherVane AFAIK, that was a DOS feature, Windows hasn't used the EOF character for many years.

Comment: while(fscanf(f, "%c", &buffer) != EOF){
  int x = 8;
  while(x--){
   //printf("%d ", temp->freq);
   char bit = buffer>>7;
   buffer <<= 1;
   if(bit == 0)
    temp = temp->left;
   else
    temp = temp->right;
   //printf("%d\n", temp->freq);
   if(temp->left == 0 && temp->right == 0){
    char *s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
    s[0] = temp->car, s[1] = '\0';
    append(s, sh);
    free(s);
    temp = ht;
   }
  }
 }
 append("\0", sh);
 // print(sh);
 *dictionary = createFromStringhelper(sh);
 fclose(f);
When it reads SUB, it just ends the function

Comment: @Flavio Put code in the question, not comments, so you can format it readably.

Comment: That code should be in the question, please.

Comment: @Barmar, MSVC still does recognise `0x1A` as the EOF marker of a text file, as I just verified. I created  binary file with that data `char txt [] = { '4', '2', 26, 'q'};` and when read back as a text file using `while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { printf ("%d\n", c);` the output was `52 50`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I wonder if it depends on whether you use `r` or `rb` mode when opening.

Comment: @Barmar: `int c; fp = fopen("test.txt", "rt"); while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {      printf ("%d\n", c);  }` So `0x1A` or `26` (sometimes known as SUB) is still treated as `EOF` perhaps for backward compatibility.

Comment: Use `rb` to read in binary mode, does it still do it?

Comment: @Barmar, no it is for a text file - obviously useless for binary data.

Comment: So is there a way to don't consider this char as EOF?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in binary mode, so that `stdio` won't treat some control characters specially. In your case, the ASCII `SUB` character is the DOS End-of-File indicator.

Use

```
f = fopen("fiename", "rb");
```

Comment: Thanks,i'm goona try this soon and then i'll tell you if it works